# Could not get unknown property 'manifestFile'

Tags: android

in Android studio gradle versions

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-4.5-20171123235935+0000-all.zip

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha04'
```

its getting this error

```
Error:Could not get unknown property 'manifestFile' for task ':backend:generateDebugRFile' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask.
```

Trying to change gradle, Studio version etc no affect

Comment: Alpha versions are meant to have issues. You can use stable versions. distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip & classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

Comment: use stable `{ classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' }`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya that is not working. I`m trying to downgrade android studio to stable version.

Comment: @Fr099y okay. try that.

Comment: Ever fix this? I having the problem on the latest AS 3.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, regular caveats about using pre-release (alpha) software apply: if you don't need to use the alpha for any particular reason, consider using the stable versions instead. Right now that means

- Android Studio 3.0.1
- [Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) 3.0.1 (a.k.a. `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`)

With that out of the way....it could be that the `3.1.0-alpha04` plugin removed support for `manifestFile`, and some other plugin you're using still depends on that. After all, the tools team [*did* remove](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#manifestOutputFile) the similarly-named `manifestOutputFile` in 3.0.

I tried building a project with

- Gradle dist 4.4-rc-3
- Android Gradle plugin 3.1.0-alpha04
- Fabric Gradle plugin 1.25.0

that applied the fabric plugin and got an error message that looks a lot like the one you posted:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'manifestFile' for task ':libs:generateProdDebugRFile' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.addPluginTasks(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:239)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.this$2$addPluginTasks(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin$_addPluginTasksToLibraryVariantsIn_closure4.doCall(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:122)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.MutableActionSet.execute(MutableActionSet.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:204)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:198)
    at com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.addVariant(LibraryExtension.java:90)
    at com.android.build.gradle.FeatureExtension.addVariant(FeatureExtension.java:108)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:132)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:709)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:695)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:613)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:609)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    ... 81 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with Crashlytics integration and found that I needed to add

`crashlytics { instantAppSupport true }`

This was needed even though I am not using Instant Apps.

Found from [this answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011581/556600)