# Fabric plugin incompatible with Gradle 4.4 +

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

Recently I have had to update my project to use Gradle 4.4 from 4.1.
i.e.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

in my gradle-wrapper.properties file.

However, this is incompabitble with the fabric plugin

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

As since the gradle update, I now get build errors when syncing my project.
Such as:

> Error:Could not get unknown property 'manifestFile' for task
>   ':Module:generateVariantFlavorRFile' of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask.

**Does anyone know when/if there will be a new plugin update that is compatible with gradle 4.4+?**

Comment: I don't think is a problem of gradle. I've made many project with crashlytics with gradle 4.
If you have followd this instruction: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started you, for sure, should be able to use crashlytics and gradle 4. 
It's a single project or is a project with some libraries always made by you? Are you using the stable gradle plugin? `{ classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' }`

Comment: @shadowsheep It's not a problem with gradle. It's a problem with the fabric plugin being incompatible with the latest version of gradle. The plugin works fine on 4.1 but not on 4.4 onwards. And I need to use gradle 4.4. My gradle build tools is already { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' }

Comment: Updated to 4.4. Got no error: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

Comment: I suggest you try with a new project. Simple Single Activity application and update your gradle plugin to 4.4 and then add crashlytics. Just to be sure you get no errors too.

Comment: @shadowsheep Yeah, created a new project added the plugin with gradle 4.4 and the issue still occurs. It only happens if you have `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` which I need as I have another module

Comment: I assure you I have applied plugin ‘io.fabric’. Tested myself. It compiles great. Did you have apply plugin in your module level or io your project level buold.gradle?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio do you have?

Comment: @shadowsheep Thanks. I am on 3.0.1. I have feature modules... Which is what might be causing the issue. I have since added `crashlytics { instantAppSupport true }` to my base feature's build.gradle and it seems to have resolved this issue. I was not sure if it was needed before, as I don't have an InstantApp, just feature modules. Probably the name is misleading if what this does is enable feature module support.

Comment: So, that's it. As for the feature module I don't know, but you can check SO if someone had the same problem with another description or post another question. C'ya!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my project included feature modules, where in the the base module's `build.gradle`, I apply the fabric plugin. i.e. `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`

It turns out that gradle version 4.4 + does work but you need to add the following:

```
crashlytics { instantAppSupport true }
```

in your base module's build.gradle. I didn't actually have an instant app, but even with feature modules in appears that this line is needed.

More info on how this can be added can be found here:
[How do I integrate Crashlytics with Android Instant Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361850/how-do-i-integrate-crashlytics-with-android-instant-apps)

Comment: Also solved my problem for this error message from Crashlytics `Could not get unknown property 'manifestFile' for task ':core:generateDebugRFile' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask.`